# Remember JDialog Sizes

Tags: java, swing, applet, java-web-start

I am having a java application and using `JDialog` in it. I am using `setMinimumSize(640,400)`. And whenever user resizes the dialog to some custom height and width. This new dimension has to be saved such that next time when the user loads the same dialog, it should render in new user customized dimension instead of minimum size.

Can someone help me how to store the new dimension in all the user sessions .?

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to use the `Preferences` API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of possible solutions you might use

## You could...

Use the `Properties` API.  This just class backed by a `HashMap` but it can easily be saved and loaded.

This API provides you with full control over where the file is saved, so you would probably want to save to to the `user.home` location to associate it with a given user.

Have a look at [the Properties trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) for more details

## You could...

Use the `Preference` API.  It provides some useful functionality which allows you to define the context in which the values are stored (ie the user or system) and it controls the storage of the values itself, so you don't need to worry about trying to save or load the values yourself

Have a look at [the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) for more details

## You could...

Simply write the data to a file yourself, using JSON, XML or simply plain old text.  This is complicated and requires a decent amount of work, but gives you complete control

## You could...

Store the values in some kind of database system, if you have one available

No matter choice you use, you'll probably find you need to write the `width` and `height` properties out individually

## How to get the dialog size?

Well, that would depend on a lot on what you are already doing.  For example, I might be tempted to create a custom dialog, which when closed, wrote out the size properties itself.  It would also load them itself it was constructed, this way, you're just relying on `JDialog#getSize`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a componentListener to your Dialog which in case of a resize can save the values:

```
dialog.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        Dimension dimension = e.getComponent().getSize();
        // save the dimension
    }
});
```